# How can I create a back button in a webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, back-button

The app consists of two activities: first - a listview with links to HTML files from assets, second - a webview with this HTML file.

So there are some links in this HTML file (in the following I call it the first HTML file) leading to other HTML files from assets. After I followed one of this links I want to go back to the first HTML file. But this method shows me a white screen instead of the file's content.

PS: I reference the second asset file from first one by an HTML link. For example (code of link in the first HTML file):

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/second.html">Second file</a>
```

Here is the **WebViewActivity** code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    WebView wWebView;

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (wWebView.canGoBack() == true) {
                    wWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String htmlFileName = "m" + bundle.getString("defStrID") + ".html";
        Context context = getBaseContext();

        try {
            String text = readAssetTextFile(context, htmlFileName);

            wWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            String summary = "<html><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
            wWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("x-data://base", summary, "text/html",
                    "utf-8", null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Exception thrown", e);
        }
    }

    public static String readAssetTextFile(Context ctx, String fileName)
            throws IOException
    {
        InputStream inputStream = ctx.getAssets().open(fileName);

        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Exception thrown", e);
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the 96th line of `onKeyDown`?

Comment: I've updated question, so the 29th line (ex 96th) is `if (wWebView.canGoBack() == true) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `wWebView` class member variable is not initialized so it is null. See this part of your code:

```
WebView wWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Perfect, you are initializing, but not what you think you are: you declare a local variable for the method and initialize it. However you shadow the class member `wWebView`, because of the local variable with the same name. Thus you do not initialize the class member, it is null and you get your [NPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Dereferencing). Change the above line to (note the absence of the type):

```
wWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

**EDIT** I was never able to make your way of navigating between the pages work. However I did certain changes to your `onCreate` method and now everything seems fine on my device:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
    title.setText(getString(R.string.app_name));

    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button infoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_info);
    infoButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String htmlFileName = "m" + bundle.getString("defStrID") + ".html";
    String LINK_TO_ASSETS = "file:///android_asset/";
    wWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wWebView.loadURL(LINK_TO_ASSETS + htmlFileName);
}
```

Now you need to change also the contents of the HTML files you load. First of all add the `<html><body>` at the beginning of each file in the assets and `</body></html>` at the end. Second now you will need to change your links. For example the link you have included in your question:

```
<a href="second.html">Second file</a>
```

As you see, these become now relative links. All these changes might make your `readAssetTextFile` useless, but I believe this is easier-to-understand code.

Comment: Thanks, this partially solved my problem. But when I press back on the second html file the screen turns white (here should be the first page). Then I press back again and app shows listview. How can I show first page?

Comment: Can you please say a bit more about the way you switch between the htnls? Is it a link you follow in the first view? Or is there some android code that does it?

Comment: Of course, app consists of two activities: first - listview with links to html files from assets, second - webview with this html file. So there are some links in this html file (Next I call it first html file). After I followed one of this links I want to go back to the first html. But this method shows me white screen instead of file.

Comment: Your code seems completely reasonable to me. Maybe it is something in the web view declaration in the layout? can you place the portion of your layout xml declaring the webview.

Comment: Still everything seems perfectly fine. Can I ask you to modify the question once more. Remove all the suggestions posted and include only two files : all the code of the activity and the layout code.

Comment: It is not difficult. Updated.

Comment: Still nothing to be found. And you still have not enough reputation for chat. Can you please place some logs in the `onKeyDown` and play through the scenario so that we can see whether the expected method is called with the expected values?

Comment: [This method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416423/need-assistance-using-phones-back-button-to-go-back-in-webview) works perfectly. May be I'm asking too much, but back button might be working if we change the code and make it possible to read files from the assets list.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? As far as I understand there are no errors in the log.

Comment: I guess you are right, the fact of loading the web view from assets screws up the history. I have some ideas how to debug and find a solution, but it will require some effort that I will not be able to do today. I don't know the solution by heart. Basically I would try using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and see what are the url I receive when back button is pressed and why the html is not loaded. I suggest you try out in this direction. I might try helping you but it will not be today for sure.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it and write about the result. So if it wouldn't be working or if you would have free time, write your suggestion, please.

Comment: I have tried various methods, but not able to adapt my code under the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. I hope very much for your help.

Comment: I tried out your code in the following way: I created html in assets and loaded it using your code in my single activity. This html links to google.com. I go to google and then with hardware back button I am able to go back without any problems. So again: there is no problem with the back functionality (or you did not properly explain what it is). I never needed to use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

Comment: I tried to do that. Link to google opens in a built-in or self-installed browser. So I can't test the functionality of the back button in such a way. Please, put 2 html files in assets. In one of them put link to the second and try out what happens when you pressing back button. When I've done so, instead of content of first html I got white screen. This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Please then update your question once more (for future generations) mentioning explicitly that both htmls are from assets. Also include how do you reference the second asset html from the first one.

Comment: Question updated. Have you tried to test back button with two files in assets, as I wrote?

Comment: No because I did not know how you refer the second html. Now you have added it, but for me at least it does not seem right. If you read the first html from the assets and also have the `secondfile.html` there the link you pasted in the question will not work (or at least for me it does not). Where does your second html reside? You refer to it with relative path, but as long as you load the first html with `InputStream`, the relative path will not point to assets.

Comment: Oh, sorry it's my fault. Link looks like `<a href="file:///android_asset/second.html">Second file</a>`

Comment: Dude I was never able to make the link from the first html to the second one work. However I made a small change in the way you load the `webView`, which should enable you to navigate back and forth and reference the file relatively. Please mind the edits of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Back button, as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it does not use up any of the screen,

Comment: Just tried this method. It crashes the app. I think to do this I need to browse histrory. Is it so?

Comment: No, not at all. But I cannot debug your app for you.

Comment: Can you look through the logcat and advice me what to do?

Comment: Are you still calling event.getAction() in your onKeyDown function? Because that will not help.

Comment: Yes, how can I do another way?

Comment: I'd tried your code, but when I'm pressing back in webview app crashes

Comment: you have not tried his code if you're still using event.getAction()

Comment: @STTLCU I tried his code and I'm no longer using two examples of back button in question. But they are partially working (if I on second html page in webview and I press back, app opens listview, but I want to go back to the 1 page)

Comment: That is very poor design. Your users will be expecting to return to the previous screen. It is not difficult, but I do not feel like explaining how to do it.

Comment: App is designed so that this function is neccessary. Otherwise I would not ask this question.

Comment: In that case you need to add an onActivityResult() function to your second activity, and call finish() in that. That will allow you to long jump back to the first one.